# A color scale legend for pyqtgraph

Tags: python-2.7, pyqtgraph

I want to put a color scale legend for a image in Pyqtgraph. The image plots the data of a pixel detector, a hit-map. I could not find any example of the same. This is how I am plotting.

```
    occupancy_graphics = pg.GraphicsLayoutWidget()
    occupancy_graphics.show()

    view = occupancy_graphics.addViewBox()
    self.occupancy_img = pg.ImageItem(border='w')

    poss = np.array([0.0, 1.0])
    color = np.array([[0,255,255,255],[255,0,255,255]], dtype=np.ubyte )
    mapp = pg.ColorMap(poss, color)
    lut = mapp.getLookupTable(0.0, 1.0, 100)
    self.occupancy_img.setLookupTable(lut, update=True)

    plot = pg.PlotWidget(viewBox=view,labels={'bottom':'Column','left':'Row'})      #Axis Labelling
    plot.addItem(self.occupancy_img)
    dock_occcupancy.addWidget(plot)
```

It is real-time plotting and the image is being updated.
Thank you.